# In Excel 2007 how to give height auto to show all text inside cell by default like Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

In Excel 2007 how to give height auto to show all text inside cell be default like Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: What do you mean? You want all cells height to be automatically adjusted for what's in them?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not really clear, but I suppose you're talking about "wrapping text"?

From [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP051998351033.aspx):

> 1. Select the cells you want to format.
> 2. On the Format menu, click Cells, and then click the Alignment
>      tab.
> 3. Under Text control, select the Wrap text check box, and then click
>      OK.
>
>    **Note**: Data in the cell will wrap to fit the column width. When you
>      change the column width, data wrapping
>      adjusts automatically.

[image: screenshot]

**Edit**: You can also apply this to a style (e.g. the 'normal' style, if you want it to really be the default for 'normal' cells, also for new documents) by right-clicking on the specific style and choose for `Modify...`.

Comment: but by default rows only shows first line of cell. i want to see all text bedefaul

Comment: @metal: Just select *all* the cells in step 1 (ctrl-a).

Comment: @metal: I think I know what you mean now... updated my answer.